# Couldn't install packages

Tags: 12.04, installation, package-management, vim

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on windows 7.

I have tried to install vim editor through terminal using `sudo apt-get install vim`
then I got the following error and couldn't install the package.  Not only this I couldn't install anything from terminal or Ubuntu center. I am sure that my internet connection is good and I could browse the internet.

This is the error I got:-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vim : Depends: vim-common (= 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2) but 2:7.3.429-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f` see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install vim
```